# Spark 3.1.3 with spark cassandra connector 3.1.0 is giving ClassNotFoundException on spark-submit even with jars attached

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, datastax-astra

I have used Spark 3.1.3 to connect Astra as well as Cassandra local server, but I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` error on `spark-submit`. I have confirmed that same is happening with spark above 3.x, this code works fine with spark 2.4.2.

Here is my `Main.scala`:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.{toSparkContextFunctions}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}


object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.config.cloud.path","/path/astradb-secure-connect.zip")
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username","client-id")
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password","client-secret")
      .setAppName("SparkTest")
    val sparkCTX = new SparkContext(conf)

    val sparkSess = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyStream").getOrCreate()
    sparkCTX.setLogLevel("Error")
    println("\n\n\n\n************\n\n\n\n")

    val Rdd = sparkCTX.cassandraTable("my_keyspace", "accounts") **// Exact Line of Error**
    Rdd.foreach(s => {
      println(s)
    })
  }
}
```

My `build.sbt` looks like:

```
name := "Synchronization"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"


scalaVersion := "2.12.15"

idePackagePrefix := Some("info.myapp.synchronization")


val sparkVersion = "3.1.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.6",
  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.4.2"
)

libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "3.1.0" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" % "jsr166e" % "1.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.4.3"

libraryDependencies += "com.sun.mail" % "javax.mail" % "1.6.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.22"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.jurajburian" %% "mailer" % "1.2.4"
```

The code I am using to run this is:

```
$ sbt package
$ spark-submit --class "Main" --jars $(echo localDependencies/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') target/scala-2.12/*jar
```

My `localDependency` folder contains jars downloaded from `mvnrepository` and looks like:

[image]

My error goes like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/CassandraRow
        at Main$.main(Main.scala:20)
        at Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 14 more
```

Please help me fix the issue, or please provide the working versions combinations

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a way around the solution. The solution is to use `sbt assembly` instead of `sbt package` and solve merger conflicts. However, if there are any solutions any solution to use `sbt package` in this way, please add as an answer.

So, here is what I did:

In folder named `project` under project root directory, there should be a `plugins.sbt` file.

```
|project root
|---project
|     |----plugins.sbt    **// This file**
|     |----build.properties
|     |----target
|     |----project
|---src
|---target
|-----|----scala-2.1x
|-------------|---xxxx.jar     **// The built jar file**
|---build.sbt      **// Add merger conflict code in here**
|---default.properties
```

In `plugins.sbt` add the line:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.15.0")
```

Later, in `build.sbt` in the `project root` directory, add this line to remove merger conflicts:

```
assemblyJarName in assembly := "my-built-fatjar-1.0.jar"
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

**Note:** 1. This merger conflict may be marked as syntax error by the editor. Also, having this merger code may stop the model from getting compiled with `sbt package` by showing error. But this works with `sbt assembly`. And the output jar would be present in `project root/target/scala-2.1x/my-built-fatjar-1.0.jar` .
2. `sbt assembly` takes several times longer than `sbt package` to build the jar. Therefore, for development purpose, use `sbt ~assembly` and this would run the build in continuous mode and the compiler would continuously look for any change in the code and it will update the jar almost instantly with all changes in the source codes.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into dependencies of the connector on Maven Repository, you will notice that it depends on the [com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector-driver_2.12](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-driver_2.12) that is missing in your list.  To simplify submission it would be simpler to use [spark-cassandra-connector-assembly](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12/3.1.0) that includes all necessary classes.

Comment: Recently I have checked that using sbt assembly with resolving merger conflicts solves the issue. I will try the method you have suggested and if that works I will mark that here.

Answer (score 0):

This line in your build file is problematic:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "3.1.0" % "provided"
```

By setting it to `provided`, not all the required dependencies get included in the build. The recommended way to define the dependencies is:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.12" % "3.1.0"
```

Alternatively, you should include the connector using the `--packages` when submitting your app. For example:

```
$ spark-submit --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.1.0
```

This will place the connector and all its dependencies in the classpath.

For more information, see the [Spark-Cassandra-connector Quick Start Guide](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md). Cheers!